# Convertir Consulta PL/SQL a Expresión LAMBDA C#

Tags: sql, lambda

buenos días!
Tengo algunos conocimientos básicos en confección de Consultas usando expresiones lambda.
En mi Models, tengo las siguientes Entidades:

```
 public class ArtistEntity
 {
     public int ArtistId { get;  set; }
     public string Name { get;  set; }
     public ICollection<AlbumEntity> Albums { get;  set; }

 }

 public class AlbumEntity
 {
     public int AlbumId { get;  set; }
     public string Title { get;  set; }
     public DateTime PublicationDate { get;  set; }
     public ArtistEntity Artist { get;  set; }
 }
```

, y no puedo resolver una consulta que en PL/SQL sería:

```
SELECT A.ArtistId, A.Name, B.Title
FROM Artist A
INNER JOIN Album B ON A.ArtistId = B.ArtistId
AND B.PublicationDate = (SELECT MAX(C.PublicationDate) FROM Album C WHERE C.ArtistId = B.ArtistId)
```

Intento recuperar el Id de Artista, Nombre de Artista, y nombre del último Álbum publicado.
Por favor, podría alguien ayudarme a traducir la consulta en un Lambda.
Desde ya muchísimas gracias

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega todo lo necesario para reproducir tu escenario, más información en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Por cierto, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Debes editar tu pregunta e incluir las clases de Album y Artist